# How to study cosmology properly?

Tags: cosmology, education

I want to study cosmology very deeply as I wanna be a cosmologist. But I am clueless about how to proceed. I have completed my BSC in physics and currently enrolled in first semester of my 4 semesters masters degree course. I am asking for a clear guidance on how to study cosmology effectively and efficiently.

I would really appreciate a list of study materials arranged topic wise including the prerequisites.

I am asking a lot of help but it will be very kind of you if you give me a clear path as I am really clueless and a little terrified too.

Please help.